# How to make use of a postgres Array in where query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

One of the table in postgreSQL has a column of datatype text[]

```
TableA:
id              uuid
tableb_ids      text[]

TableB:
id              uuid
name            text
```

Now I need to write a query like:

```
select * from tableB where id in (select tableb_ids from tableA where id ="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx")
```

I cannot change the schema/table definitions.
i.e) I cannot keep many entries for every entry of tableB in tableA. TableA is a complex table.

Comment: Something like `SELECT b.* FROM tableb b JOIN tablea  a ON b.id = ANY(a.tableb_ids)`

Comment: @404 I get `ERROR:  operator does not exist: uuid = text[]` when I try that way

Comment: `b.id::TEXT = ANY(a.tableb_ids)`

Comment: Why do you have a `text` array containing `uuid` values? If you really need the de-normalization, `tableb_ids` should be defined as `uuid[]`

Comment: I can change that @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @404 But the problem is I will be joining other tables to fetch more data, but I keep getting this error `column "tablec.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Since I use `Any`

Comment: @Surya You'll need to show your new query then.

Comment: @Surya: please do not extend your question once you have an answer to your initial problem. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: @404: you should add that as an answer, so it can be accepted and the question can be marked as resolved

Comment: Ok @a_horse_with_no_name not extending and yeah

Comment: @404 please do add that as the answer will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find records in one table whose record ids are contained in an array in some other table, you can join on the tables:

```sql
SELECT b.*
FROM tableb b
INNER JOIN tablea a
    ON b.id::TEXT = ANY(a.tableb_ids)
    AND a.id = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'
```

Another way you could do it:

```sql
SELECT b.*
FROM tableb b
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT UNNEST(a.tableb_ids)
    FROM tablea a
    WHERE a.id = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'
) x
-- not sure if the aliases are needed in the subquery
```